# Scraping text from html table in r

Tags: r, web-scraping

i'm pretty new to R and i'm trying to solve some real world challenges while taking datacamp.com R course. The thing is: i'm trying to scrape address, name, phone, email and site from a webpage. The information is on a table. I have tried this code:

```
library(rvest)
# Store web url
apel_url <- read_html("http://www.apel.pt/pageview.aspx?pageid=944&langid=1")
txt <- html_text(apel_url)
txt
associados <- apel_url %>% 
html_nodes(css = "p.MsoNormal") %>%
html_text() 
print(associados)
```

As result i have a chr [1:1481] string but some of the lines were scraped joined with each other, although in the site they are separate lines. For instance:

```
associados[969]
```

results in:

```
[1] "PENUMBRA EDITORA, LDA.Rua da Marinha, 50 - Madalena4405-761 VILA NOVA DE GAIA Tel.: 22 375 04 52"
```

I wonder what i'm missing and would like to know which is the best way to transform this string in a dataframe separating each field in a column (phone, address, email, URL, etc). Some of the entrances have 1 or more phone numbers, other don't have URL, etc, so it has to be blank when there is no information.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you view the source for this line, you can see that it is all enclosed within the same <p> tag, which is why isn't coming as one line, whereas most others are broken up into separate <p> tags. This will be difficult to scrape correctly without standard rules for how the information is organized.

Comment: Any clues ? Should i scrape each element separately or is there any other workaround ? It seems at first glance an easy page to scrape.